# The treeview IsSelected and IsExpanded not working

Tags: xml, c#-4.0

I have created the XMLDataPropety in my ViewModel and Bind it to the treeview in my View. This is working fine, the problem is that the IsSeleted and IsExpanded is not working. How can I Get the selected node every time the user clicks on the tree?